# MAC OS X 10.6.8 - Uninstalling VMWare Fusion

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, vmware-fusion

Does anyone know if uninstalling Fusion (using the correct uninstaller for it), also uninstall Windows and associated apps?
If not, is there a correct sequence to get rid of all things Windows related? In other words, how do I get rid of the Windows files and recover the hard disk space?

Comment: Delete the Virtual Disk file. .vmdk is the filetype, you can also search for it. It contains _everything_ related to the given virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

The VMware Fusion uninstaller works like most uninstallers: it uninstalls all parts of the program, but not the data you created with it (in this case, the virtual machines you created). If you also want to delete the virtual machines, just drag them to the Trash; they're usually in the Virtual Machines folder in the Documents folder in your home folder.